# Form Validation : Checkbox input through PHP

Tags: php, validation

Hey I just wanted to know how do we check if a user has checked a checkbox or not in a form after hitting the submit buttom . I am using PHP so any help regarding that would be really appreciated . 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your effort?

Comment: can you post your checkbox code here?

Comment: <input name="agree" type="checkbox" value="Check" />

Comment: do some basic search before asking to stack..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox_name']) && $_POST['checkbox_name']!="")
{
    echo 'checkbox is checked'; 
}
```

Comment: thanks I was using 'name'  of the checkbox instead the 'value' .

Comment: Hey I have a little more doubt now , whats the difference between using a 'name' and 'value' in an input checkbox ?

Comment: `name` and `value` are totally different `attributes` of a checkbox. `name` is used to fetch the value of element, and `value` is the value of that element.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='boxname' value='1' />

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['boxname'])
    {
        echo "check box is checked";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' name='theName' value='itsChecked'>
```

PHP

```
if($_POST['theName'] == 'itsChecked'){}
```

Comment: Where's the `name` attribute?

Comment: Good point..
Input needs name='theName' & If statement will be $_POST['theName'] instead.

Comment: It's better to use `isset` first and then compare `==` to avoid warnings